# database.yml in Rails reconnect set to true or false

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In `database.yml`, the default settings for `reconnect` on Rails 3 and 4 is `false`. What is the common setting, and in what circumstances we should set it to `true`? Thanks.

Comment: You set it to true when you want the db driver to reconnect after connection failure, I think. :)

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538900/under-what-circumstances-would-you-want-rails-to-be-set-not-to-reconnect-to-mysq?rq=1

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Then I am not sure why one should set it to `false`... Hmm...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can set it true. This option is introduced in Rails 2.3

MySQL supports a reconnect flag in its connections - if set to true, then the client will try reconnecting to the server before giving up in case of a lost connection. You can now set reconnect = true for your MySQL connections in database.yml to get this behavior from a Rails application.

Rails team set this option default as 'false' because, they don't want to change the behavior of existing applications.

But some side effects are there if we set `reconnect = true`. It is not transaction-safe.The MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/auto-reconnect.html) in fact explicitly states that the auto-reconnect feature affects transactions.

Any active transactions are rolled back and autocommit mode is reset.

Applications that are not written to deal with this could easily break. The documentation also lists a number of other side effects caused by the auto-reconnect feature, all of which could cause applications not written to anticipate the behavior to function incorrectly or fail.

check:

[rails 2.3 release notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/2_3_release_notes.html)

[mysql-reconnect-value-doesnt-stick](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/1797-mysql-reconnect-value-doesnt-stick)

[see this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538900/under-what-circumstances-would-you-want-rails-to-be-set-not-to-reconnect-to-mysq)

Comment: Now that that option (and the underlying MySQL option MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT) is being removed, how can I make a Rails app reconnect rather than becoming permanently disconnected?