# Force to reconnect MySQL in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, reconnect

How to force MySQL reconnect at my will in Rails application? I would like to do this either periodically or on DB exceptions like "MySQL server has gone away".

I found `ActiveRecord::Base.remove_connection` but as it is written, it should be called for some model, not the whole application.

Answer (score 22):

It's a huge pain to restart the Rails console when I'm running it via Heroku with a bunch of objects in variables and then lose my database connection.

The following is code I would not consider "good" to put in your actual application but it temporarily gets over the oft encountered `Mysql2::Error: closed MySQL connection` in a console:

```
 ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reconnect!
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using *reconnect = true* in your database.yml as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21594429/database-yml-in-rails-reconnect-set-to-true-or-false)?

Comment: Doesn't work. I am getting disconnects and then "out of memory" in MySQL2 client. Then WEBrick/Puma stops.